# Stop Swiping after the end of the items in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using `Viewflipper` in my application where I am getting some(x) number of items in the `Viewflipper`.

Now what is happening is that it showing the first item in the continuous scroll after the last item.

I need to stop it as the scrolling needs to get stopped in any particular direction after the last item is reached and vice a versa.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

If you are using timed interval flipping, you can call `stopFlipping()` when you hit the last view.

If you are doing it manually via `showNext()` and `showPrevious()`, then you can simply set a flags in your code to check for the first and last views and handle the swipe actions. For example:

```
if(lastFlag==true)
{

}
else
{
 vf.showNext();
}
```

Here's a good tutorial on using ViewFlipper:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634